# multi-variate normal distribution distance from vector sub-space

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, normal-distribution

let $X\sim {\cal N}(\mu,C)$ be a random variable obeying multi-variate normal distribution in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector space with $\dim(U)=n-1$.
What is the probability of $X$ to be at distance ($L_2$) $d$ from $U$? Assume that $d$ is small (I actually interested in $\lim\limits_{d \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{P(d)}{d}$ where $P(d)$ is the above probability).

Comment: To maximize the number and the quality of the responses you receive, you should explain what you have already tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Do you mean distance _at least_ $d$, or maybe distance _at most_ $d$?  The probability that the distance is _exactly_ $d$ is $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the "$L_2$" distance, so that means what you're looking for is the norm of the projection of $X$ onto the $1$-dimensional orthogonal complement of $U$.  Let $a$ be a unit vector (i.e. $\|a\|=1$) orthogonal to $U$.  Then the length of the orthogonal projection of $X$ on $a$ is just $a^\top X$. Here I'm thinking of $a$ and $X$ as column vectors in $\mathbb R^{n\times1}$, so that $a^\top$ is a row vector, in $\mathbb R^{1\times n}$, and $a^\top X$ is a scalar-valued random variable.  You have $X\sim {\cal N}(\mu, C)$ and $\mu\in\mathbb R^{n\times 1}$, and $C$ is an $n\times n$ non-negative definite real matrix.  It follows that
$$
a^\top X\sim {\cal N}(a^\top\mu, a^\top C a).
$$
This is a one-dimensional normal distribution.  What your asking for is the distribution of $|a^\top X|$, since that is the distance from $X$ to the subspace $U$.

Comment: thank you. can you please refer me to the derivation of the formula in the middle?

Comment: @user36626 : Suppose $X$ is a random vector taking values in $\mathbb R^{n\times 1}$ and you define $C=\operatorname{var}(X)$ $=\mathbb E((X-\mu)(X-\mu)^\top)$ so that $C\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, where $\mu=\mathbb E(X)$. Suppose $A\in\mathbb R^{k\times n}$, so that $A\mu\in\mathbb R^{k\times 1}$. Then $\mathbb E(AX)=A\mu$ and $\operatorname{var}(AX)$ must be a $k\times k$ matrix. So $\operatorname{var}(AX)$ $=\mathbb E((AX-A\mu)(AX-A\mu)^\top)$ $= A\mathbb E((X-\mu)(X-\mu)^\top))A^\top$ $=ACA^\top$. If you post a separate question about this, I can go into more detail.

Comment: (In particular, we used the fact that $(A(X-\mu))^\top$ (with $A$ on the left) is equal to $(X-\mu)^\top A^\top$ (with $A^\top$ on the right).)